# Display college classes and make title bold

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to make the course title bold with no success. I tried using the id with no success either even if I do `font-weight:bold;`. Lastly, is this a good way to display college courses? I will later have to retrieve the data from a database and so far using mock up data generates tables just fine, but I'm not that familiar with displaying on the front-end.

```
<div class="classes_wrapper">
        <div class="classes_wrapper_title"><h4>COURSES I AM TAKING</h4></div>
        <div id="my_classes">
            <table class="classes">
                <tr id="course_title">
                    <td><h4>Cal & Analytic Geometry</h4></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="course_info">
                    <td><h5>MA 2330/ Section 001</h5></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="time_frame">
                    <td><h5>August 31, 2020 - December 22, 2020</h5></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="course_time">
                    <td><h5>Tue,Thu 01:00PM - 02:30PM</h5></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="course_setting">
                    <td><h5>REMOTE</h5></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide your css code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way.

I noticed all of your classes were already inside `<h5>` tags so they were already bold.

I removed those tags and targeted all `tds` in your code with this css to make them all bold:

```
td {
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Lastly, how you display data is up to you. When you later retrieve the data from a database, you will have to use some programming that will not be a part of your HTML.

```css
td {
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="classes_wrapper">
        <div class="classes_wrapper_title"><h4>COURSES I AM TAKING</h4></div>
        <div id="my_classes">
            <table class="classes">
                <tr id="course_title">
                    <td>Cal & Analytic Geometry</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="course_info">
                    <td>MA 2330/ Section 001</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="time_frame">
                    <td>August 31, 2020 - December 22, 2020</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="course_time">
                    <td>Tue,Thu 01:00PM - 02:30PM</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="course_setting">
                    <td>REMOTE</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Amazing, I didn't know <h5> made them bold I just wanted to make the font bigger but I'll do it from CSS. For the data retrieving I have mock up data using Jquery which works which is why each row has an Id. I'm not sure if that is the best way.

Comment: How about making class_wrapper resize according to text and not the window. In my css i have it as width:50%; which for text is a lot when in full screen, but when I resize the browser window to half it looks fine.

Comment: Do you mean you want to resize the text based on a percentage? You can do that but when you set font-size as a percentage the font will inherit the parent elements size and manage its width accordingly.

Comment: No I want the wrapper to resize  but keep the same left and right distance from the text. I have it set up at 50% and when the browser is in full screen it's huge sideways compared to the text inside in this case the course description.

Comment: Hmm, if that works for you then it's a fine solution. - Without seeing the code I can't really determine what you may need to do. You can maybe set the wrapper to 100% and apply margins to maintain distance. -  Feel free to create another question if needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="classes_wrapper">
        <div class="classes_wrapper_title"><h4>COURSES I AM TAKING</h4></div>
        <div id="my_classes">
            <table class="classes">
                <tr id="course_title">
                    <td>Cal & Analytic Geometry</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="course_info">
                    <td>MA 2330/ Section 001</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="time_frame">
                    <td>August 31, 2020 - December 22, 2020</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="course_time">
                    <td>Tue,Thu 01:00PM - 02:30PM</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="course_setting">
                    <td>REMOTE</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>


and 

td {
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Please provide description